# Historical stock data

Tags: r

I want to get the closing prices for all S&P 500 stocks for specific dates.

I've trawled SO for answers and they fall into the following:

1. Download specific stocks for S&P with start and end dates - returns more than closing price which would require  a line to concatenate all stocks and slows it right down
2. Download all stocks for S&P with start and end dates - always gets "Error in download"

For instance:

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

first.date <- Sys.Date() - 160
last.date <- Sys.Date() - 1

all_stocks <- GetSP500Stocks()
tickers <- all_stocks$tickers

show <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers,
                     first.date = first.date,
                     last.date = last.date)
```

This always returns:

```
"Adobe Systems Inc | yahoo (7|505) | Not Cached

- Error in download..
```

and so on.

I merely want three columns - ticker, first.date and last.date

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tickers` as `all_stocks$company` instead of `all_stocks$tickers`

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

tickers <- all_stocks$company
show <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers,
                        first.date = first.date,last.date = last.date)
```

It seems unconventional to me though that column with ticker information is given column name as `company` and column with company names is given name as `tickers`.

Comment: @Foothill_trudger I guess all the information you need is present in `show$df.tickers`. Would you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can find constituents of the S&P 500 here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols("MMM;ABT;ABBV;ABMD;ACN;
ATVI;ADBE;AMD;AAP;AES;AMG;AFL;A;APD;
AKAM;ALK;ALB;ARE;ALXN;ALGN;ALLE;AGN;ADS;
LNT;ALL;GOOGL", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
head(pframe)
```

Try this too.

```
library(quantmod)

Nasdaq100_Symbols <- c('GE','PG','MSFT','AAPL','PFE','AMD','DELL')

# put all stocks in one list object    
stocks <- lapply(Nasdaq100_Symbols, getSymbols, auto.assign = FALSE)

# following is not needed but if you want to use the list for other purposes 
# it is a good practice to name all the different list objects.

# names(stocks) <- Nasdaq100_Symbols


# merge all stocks into 1 xts object
nasdaq100 <- Reduce(merge, stocks)

# fill NA's with 0
nasdaq100 <- na.fill(nasdaq100, 0)

outcomeSymbol <- "GE.Volume" # <-- used GE as that data is available in the downloaded data set

# merge outcome to data
nasdaq100 <- merge(nasdaq100, lm1 = lag(nasdaq[, outcomeSymbol], -1))

# turn into data.frame
nasdaq100_df <- data.frame(date = index(nasdaq100), coredata(nasdaq100))
```

Finally, try this to get the tickers.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
SP500 <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()
SP500 <- SP500[[1]]
SP500
```

As an alternative, see the links below for more ideas of how to do this.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/downloading-sp-500-stock-data-from-googlequandl-with-r-command-line-script/

https://www.business-science.io/investments/2016/10/23/SP500_Analysis.html

https://www.business-science.io/investments/2016/11/30/Russell2000_Analysis.html